# Add download progress RestTemplate in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

so I am downloading some files using Spring Rest template. I have a requirement to log the progress of the download in backend itself.
So can the download progress be logged in some way ?

Here is my implementation :

```
File file = restTemplate.execute(FILE_URL, HttpMethod.GET, null, clientHttpResponse -> {
    File ret = File.createTempFile("download", "tmp");
    StreamUtils.copy(clientHttpResponse.getBody(), new FileOutputStream(ret));
    return ret;
});
```

PS: I was thinking if there is a way to intercept how much of the response body is transferred.